# jQuery: Button cannot be clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code structure:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="button_login">Login</a>
</div>

<script>

function login() {
    alert('button works!');
};

$("#button_login").on('click', function(e) {                                    
    e.preventDefault();
    login();
});

</script>
```

Please also see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLseX/)

Why does the button not work?

Comment: You must include jQuery to your fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/ZLseX/2/

Comment: didnt include jquery in it. http://jsfiddle.net/ZLseX/1/

Comment: Include `JQuery.js` file

Comment: This can be reproduced in IE11, but not Chrome. Appears to be a problem that jsFiddle has with JavaScript generally, rather than this specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not including jQuery in your fiddle. I added `jQuery 2.0.2`.

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLseX/3/

Answer (score -1):

1. you must attach jquery library into your html document
2. add onclick into `a` element

i changed your code!

## Demo

---

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="button_login" onclick='login();'>Login</a>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
function login() {
    alert('button works!');
};

$("#button_login").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    login();
});
```

Comment: No, why are you use onclick="login();" on the element and delegating the onclick on the element with the same code....? OP's code is perfectly fine.

Comment: see title! **button cannot be clicked!** it was a way for test it! @Anton

Comment: The only reason why it couldn't be clicked was because the jQuery was not included...

Comment: exactly!!! i added `onclick` only for test and showing @Anton

Answer (score -2):

Please know how to work with jsfiddle. Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLseX/5/)

```
    function login() {
       alert('button works!');
    }

     $("#button_login").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        login();
     });
```